# Continue to read in file after if statement

Tags: python, list, csv

Given an if statement is true, I want to continue and append the next four lines of a CSV file reader to a list. How is this possible with the CSV class?

```
for j in range(3):
    f = open("Trial_"+ str(num) + "_Game_" + str(j) + ".csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    f.next()
    for line in reader:
        all_decisions.append(map(int,line))
        if all_decisions[-1][4] == 1: 
            for k in range(4):
                # append the next line in the reader to all_decisions here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `iter` of `reader`, loop over that instead of `reader` directly, and call `next()` on the `iter` 4 times in your `if` statement:

```
reader_iter = iter(reader)  # <-- using this in both loops
for line in reader_iter:
    all_decisions.append(map(int, line))
    if all_decisions[-1][4] != 1:
        for _, kline in zip(range(4), reader_iter): # zip stops after range(4). we only need kline
            all_decisions.append(kline)
```

By making the `iter` `reader_iter`, you can call `next()` in your `range(4)` loop as well as (automatically) in the main loop

---

Edit: per @JonClements' comment, `reader` is already an `iter`, so using `islice` on it will work automagically:

```
for line in reader:
    all_decisions.append(map(int, line))
    if all_decisions[-1][4] != 1:
        all_decisions.extend(islice(reader, 4))
```

Though my first example is still a nice exercise on how iterables work :)

Comment: Might want to consider use of `islice` here - something like `kline = next(islice(reader, 4, None))` and then you don't need the `iter(reader)` is an iterable anyway so will be consumed... (or whatever way around the OP is trying to do it... append the next 4 afer the statement).... `somelist.extend(list(islice(reader, 4)))` or something might do it....

Comment: ah good point. i was using a mock range() to check my work, and it didn't occur to me `reader` was already an `iter`